# anaconda-navigator does not start

Tags: anaconda

I installed anaconda 4.8.3 on a openSuSE Leap 15.2 (KDE Plasma), but when I try to start `anaconda-navigator`, I get:

```
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A system update fixed it. Can't say, which one exactly.