# Anaconda-navigator does not start after installation on Tumbleweed

Tags: anaconda3

Similar to [anaconda-navigator does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755233/anaconda-navigator-does-not-start),
I could not start anaconda-navigator after installation.

My system is:

```
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20200826"
ID="opensuse-tumbleweed"
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20200826"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20200826"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
LOGO="distributor-logo"
```

I ran:

```
(base) xxxx@xxxx:~> anaconda-navigator
```

,and got:

```
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I installed it following https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/ (dependencies, checked) and running `bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh`

[anaconda-navigator does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755233/anaconda-navigator-does-not-start) said a system update solved the problem. But, that didn't do it for me. There was no update left for zypper to do.

I can run conda and anaconda commands, but I can't run GUI software. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message.

With running
xhost +
first I can start anaconda-navigator. But this seems a rather desperate hack ....